# Склонение фамилии Кребс

Tags: ономастика, склонение-фамилий

Склоняется ли мужская фамилия Кребс?

Answer (score 1):

Мужские фамилии, оканчивающиеся на согласную,  склоняются (энциклопедия Брокгауза).

Answer (score 1):

Склоняется.

- И.п. *Кребс*
- Р.п. *Кребса*
- Д.п. *Кребсу*
- В.п. *Кребса*
- Т.п. *Кребсом*
- П.п. *о Кребсе*